# Is there any way to render a html file in a markdown post with Docusaurus?

Tags: plotly, docusaurus

I am trying to convert a blog from Jekyll to Docusaurus and am having an issue figuring out how to render an HTML file from within the markdown post.

In Jekyll, I am able to do so like so:

```
{% include [filename].html %}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do something similar in Docusaurus.

If relevant, the html file is created via a Python Plotly figure.

Any help or hints appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news? **It is possible.**

The bad news? You may have to edit the HTML to fit the `mdx` rules… Or use `iframe`.

---

**Example 1** (using iframe)

In your docs folder…

1. Create a `html` file with all your `HTML`, like `page.html`.
2. Create a file with the extension `.mdx`, like `intro.mdx`.

*intro.mdx*

```
# Rendering HTML

Some important information.

<iframe src='page.html' width='100%'></iframe>
```

*page.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .myDiv {border: 5px outset red; background-color: lightblue; text-align: center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Example 2** (editing the HTML)

Create a file with the extension `.mdx` inside your `docs` folder, like `intro.mdx`, and insert the following to check it out.

Pay attention to the `{{`, and that the attribute `background-color` was changed to `backgroundColor`.

*intro.mdx*

```
# Rendering HTML

Some important information.

<div style={{ padding: '20px', backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}>
    <h3>This is JSX</h3>
</div>
```

See [the docs of docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react) and [the docs of MDX](https://mdxjs.com/) to understand it better.

Comment: The iFrame solution was exactly what I needed.  Unfortunately the html file in this case is complicated to modify since it is the output of a plotly HTML export.

Comment: I am glad that my answer could help you! I thought so when writing the "Example 2" that you could have a lot of trouble... Then I remember iframe and tested it, luck! (if possible, please mark this answer as "accepted")

Answer (score 0):

I hacked at this for a while and eventually ended up doing the following:

1. Added my `page.html` file to the `img` folder
2. Added the iframe to my page:

```
<iframe src="/img/page.html" height="1050px" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```