# Can't embed a CodeSandbox iframe into Docusaurus document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, docusaurus, codesandbox

I can't figure out what's causing it, but I've been able to embed a youtube video iframe, but for some reason, the CodeSandbox iframe keeps causing a build error and it won't work. Are there some limitations to iframe embeds I need to watch out for that I may be able to fix?

Comment: Consider using the [react-player](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193176/5734097) or [check this for iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68104885/5734097) ideas.

Comment: I tried to paste some iframe code for YouTube, and it worked... Add more information about the errors that you are getting. Also, I had trouble using two `html` tags next to each other, if that's your case, try to add a line between then.

Answer (score 0):

So after messing around with the different attributes it seems having a Style tag on the iframe is what's causing it to fail the build for some reason, removing the style tag allows it to build and the iframe embeds work well now.